# Is it possible to change the Python interpreter version DreamPie is using?

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x

I have both Python 3.1 and Python 2.7 installed on my system. I'm usually using Python 3.1 but sometimes I need to use Python 2.7.

The Python shell I'm using is [DreamPie](http://dreampie.sourceforge.net/) which supports both 3.1 and 2.7. By default, it's using Python 3.1.

Is it possible to tell DreamPie "Please use 2.7 for now" and later return to 3.1 by telling DreamPie "great, now use 3.1"?

If so, then how? Otherwise, what else can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the path to your python2 executable...

```
dreampie /path/to/python2.x
```